# Passing props to a subpage with a query in the URL causes 431 Request Header Fields Too Large

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a page called campaigns, and on the index page I want to forward the data to my dynamic page `[campaignId].tsx`.

Managed to see the data on my dynamic page but url links getting too long until it's getting an HTTP Status code 431 header too long whenever I tried to refresh the page.

Here is my `index.tsx`:

```
const DisplayCampaigns = ({
  title,
  isLoading,
  campaigns,
}: DisplayCampaignsProps) => {
  

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="font-epilogue font-semibold text-[18px] text-white text-left">
        {title} ({campaigns.length})
      </h1>
      <div className="flex flex-wrap mt-[20px] gap-[26px]">
        {isLoading && (
          <Image
            src={loader}
            alt="loader"
            className="w-[100px] h-[100px] object-contain"
          />
        )}

        {!isLoading && campaigns.length === 0 && (
          <p className="font-epilogue font-semibold text-[14px] leading-[30px] text-[#818183]">
            You have not created any campaigns yet
          </p>
        )}

        {!isLoading &&
          campaigns.length > 0 &&
          campaigns.map((campaign: any) => (
            <Link
              href={{
                pathname: `/campaigns/${campaign.title}`,
                query: { ...campaign },
              }}
            >
              <FundCard key={campaign.pId} {...campaign} />
            </Link>
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Is there a way I can refactor it so that the url can be shortened and still able to pass the props to my dynamic page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you did, the URL will contain as many query strings as `campaign` has properties, and will be as long as the length of all these properties put together. And a server, called when you refresh the page, reserves only a limited amount of memory for the header of a request. [For the latest Node.js version, by default, it's 16384 (16 KiB)](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html). This is your problem.

You could only put the `id` of the campaign in the URL. Grab it on `[campaignId.tsx]`, and then, you either fetch the campaign in a `useEffect` with a network call, from a context, or with a serverside function like `getServerSideProps`.

To do so, change the redirection inside `index.tsx` to:

```js
<Link
  href={{
    pathname: `/campaigns/${campaign.id}`,
  }}
>
  <FundCard key={campaign.pId} {...campaign} />
</Link>
```

Then on `[campaignId.tsx]` get the campaign with `fetch`, or from a global state, using the passed `id`:

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Campaign() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [campaign, setCampaign] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (router.isReady) {
      // You can fetch it from an API, or from a global state, like a context
      fetch(`/api/${router.query.campaignId}`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => setCampaign(data));
    }
  }, [router]);
  if (!campaign) {
    return "Loading...";
  }
  return <div>{campaign.title}</div>;
}
```

Or, on `[campaignId.tsx]`, use `getServerSideProps` and fetch the campaign on the server:

```js
export default function Campaign({ campaign }) {
  return <div>{campaign.title}</div>;
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const res = await fetch(`/api/${context.query.campaignId}`);
  const data = await res.json();
  return {
    props: { campaign: data }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, managed to fetch it and it can display all the data in my [campaignId].tsx